# I accidentally put aluminum foil in my microwave, how can I clean the scorch marks?

Tags: cleaning, microwave, aluminum-foil

I have a microwave/grill combo and I accidentally had aluminum foil inside when starting the microwave function. By the time I realized it was already sparking and left brown scorch marks on the inside.

The inside walls of my microwave look to be stainless steel or some type of metal. I tried scrubbing these with some soap but it didn't do much. Is there any remedy to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your microwave's owner's manual for a cleaning procedure and follow it.

If there isn't one, I'd try the procedure recommended by [Samsung](http://techlife.samsung.com/clean-scorched-microwave-oven-1334.html) which I've summarized below:

1. Sprinkle baking soda over the interior of the oven and rub the entire thing with a damp cloth. Wipe clean with damp cloths.
2. Make a 1 : 8 vinegar to water solution by volume (at least 130 mL of this stuff) and microwave until its boiling rapidly. Leave in oven for 15 minutes then wipe down with damp cloths.
3. Use acetone (in many nail polish removers) on a cloth to remove scorch marks. Wipe clean with damp cloths.
4. Put some instant coffee powder in some water and microwave it until your microwave doesn't have an acetone smell.

You may have to repeat step 4 a few times; basically, just make something that smells pleasant a few times so the scent of acetone goes away.

Answer (score 1):

For my motorcycle I am using [Autosol bluing remover](https://www.autosol.com/Bluing_Remover_p/1290.htm), a metal polish paste.

That works pretty good on almost any other kind of metal. Used for hood in a kitchen.

Comment: On the inside of an microwave? Have you actually tried that? I would not want a residue of that.

Comment: Stainless steel works pretty well.

Comment: good to know, but where i live I can't get this specific product

Answer (score -2):

100% pure tea tree oil just removed my burn stains with no problem

Comment: do you mean tea tree oil to remove burn stains from inside the microwave? and I assume from the downvotes I'm not the only one who haven't heard of it before.